# Memory Location Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat PeperAndSalt(Mat *,int);

int main()

{
    Mat image,image2;

    try
    {
        image = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg");

        if(!image.data)
        {
            throw 1;
        }
    }
    catch(int a)
    {
        cout << "Error. Image does not exist" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    //Display Normal Image
    namedWindow("Normal Image");
    imshow("Normal Image",image);

    //Edited Image
    image2 = PeperAndSalt(&image,3000);

    namedWindow("Edited Image");
    imshow("Edited Image",image2);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

Mat PeperAndSalt(Mat *imagePtr, int numberOfPixels)
{
    srand(numberOfPixels);

    Mat newMat;

    imagePtr->copyTo(newMat);

    for(int a=0;a<numberOfPixels;a++)
    {
        int column = rand()%newMat.cols;
        int row = rand()%newMat.rows;

        if(newMat.channels()==1)
        {
            //Grey Image
            newMat.at<uchar>(column,row)= 255;
        }
        else if(newMat.channels()==3)
        {
            //Colour Image
            newMat.at<Vec3b>(column,row)[0]=255;
            newMat.at<Vec3b>(column,row)[1]=255;
            newMat.at<Vec3b>(column,row)[2]=255;
        }
    }

    return newMat;
}
```

This code generates the following error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x756a9617 in OpenCV1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x003bf2a0..
```

Why is this? Please help!

Edit

Here is the error, which occurs in Mat.hpp, which is an inbuilt class of OpenCV. I got this while debugging

[image]

**Edit**

Error is at this line

```
image2 = PeperAndSalt(&image,3000);
```

Comment: Did you debug? If so, what line generates the exception?

Comment: Well, as there's `Unhandler exception`, than `handle` it (use `try-catch`) and see what's the exception + its description

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: To be honest, I don't know how to do proper debug in VS. When I press F11 for debug, it shows issues when it calls opencv classes

Comment: @Yohan F11 is step into, try with F10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `newMat.at<...>(column,row)` with `newMat.at<...>(row,column)`.

Here's a part of the code.

```
    if(newMat.channels()==1)
    {
        //Grey Image
        newMat.at<uchar>(row,column)= 255;
    }
    else if(newMat.channels()==3)
    {
        //Colour Image
        newMat.at<Vec3b>(row,column)[0] = 255;
        newMat.at<Vec3b>(row,column)[1] = 255;
        newMat.at<Vec3b>(row,column)[2] = 255;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to GDB's output:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x00000001029fe2ed
0x0000000100001f60 in PeperAndSalt (imagePtr=0x7fff5fbff820, numberOfPixels=3000) at chrys.cpp:65
65              newMat.at<Vec3b>(column,row)[0]=255;
```

the crash happens in:

```
newMat.at<Vec3b>(column,row)[0]=255;
```

and that means that **you are trying to access a position on the `Mat` that doesn't exists**. Either `column` or `row` are not in a valid range.

Happy hunting!